# How to define return type in PHP and handle the Exceptions?

Tags: php, laravel, exception

I want to define return type of method in PHP(specially in Laravel)
For example for getting a model by Id:

```
public function show(int $id) {
    try{
         $student = Student::first($id);
         return $student;
        }
    catch(Exception $exp){
        throw Exception($exp)
        }
}
```

The code works with no issues but when I try to define the return type (Student in this example) in front of the method:

```
public function show(int $id) : Student
```

I get the error which says the explicited return type doesn't match with return value of the method.

How can I define the return type and handle the Exceptions?

Comment: Can I ask what the point of the exception handling is? You can use `Student::firstOrFail($id)` which will throw an error and force return a JSON response, saying that no entity was found for the provided ID. If you really want to deal with the exception (`first()` doesn't throw any, since it returns `null` if the query returns empty) you can select the student from the DB and then do a check to validate if the student is null or not (`if (is_null($student) { ... }` or `if (!($student instanceof Student)) { ... }`), if it is throw a `StudentNotFoundException` (create it).

Comment: This snip code is just a sample. I asked for any other complicated cases with various possible return types.
If I create StudentNotFoundException, I still couldn't define the return type, could I?

Comment: You could add `/** @throws StudentNotFoundException */` above the function, so you can be warned by the IDE on where you call that same function. An exception is not a return type, you can keep returning `Student` as you're doing right now (
`/**
* @return Student
* @throws StudentNotFoundException
* @throws AnotherException
*/`)

Answer (score 1):

Use `find()` method instead of `first()`...
Why? Let's see:

```
// This code
User::first($id);
// is equivalent to this SQL statement:
select `5` from `users` limit 1 
//which causes unknown column name 

// This code
User::find($id);
// is equivalent to this SQL statement:
select * from `users` where id = $id limit 1 
//which retrieves the first matching student by id and it's the correct way!
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your method may return a different type of data you should use a safety operator before defining the return type.

**Example**

```
public function show():?Student { 
    // body 
}
```

Or explicitly you can define more than two return types for your method using the pipe `(|)` character in PHP.

**Example**

```
public function show(): Student|Exception { 
   // body 
}
```

In the above's example, you're simply mentioning that the `show()` method can return either a `Student` Object or an `Exception` Object.